# Unit testing concept, should these assertions be splitted to be "unit"?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Despite the fact that I'm being playing for a little while with unit testing, I can't really get the concept of "unit", that is a single functionality.

For example, I'm testing a group of magic methods in the form of `newXxx`:

```php
public function testMagicCreatorWithoutArgument()
{
    $retobj = $this->hobj->newFoo();

    // Test that magic method sets the attribute
    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('foo', $this->hobj);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(get_class($this->hobj), $this->hobj->foo);

    // Test returned $retobj type
    $this->assertInstanceOf(get_class($this->hobj), $retobj);
    $this->assertNotSame($this->hobj, $retobj);

    // Test parent property in $retobj
    $this->assertSame($this->hobj, $retobj->getParent());
}
```

As you can see there are three "groups" of assertions in this test method. Should I split them into three single test methods, in order to follow the "unit testing" principle?

Split would be something like:

```php
public function testMagicCreatorWithoutArgumentSetsTheProperty()
{
    $this->hobj->newFoo();

    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('foo', $this->hobj);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(get_class($this->hobj), $this->hobj->foo);
}

/**
 * @depends testMagicCreatorWithoutArgumentReturnsNewInstance
 */
public function testMagicCreatorWithArgumentSetsParentProperty()
{
    $retobj = $this->hobj->newFoo();

    $this->assertSame($this->hobj, $retobj->getParent());
}

public function testMagicCreatorWithoutArgumentReturnsNewInstance()
{
    $retobj = $this->hobj->newFoo();

    $this->assertInstanceOf(get_class($this->hobj), $retobj);
    $this->assertNotSame($this->hobj, $retobj);
}
```

Comment: From what I understand "unit" in "Unit Testing" refers to testing the "units" (as classes and methods) as a contrast to testing the whole application. So "unit" doesn't require you to split it to 3 methods, but just does require you to isolate tests in general.

Comment: @zerkms ok, so do you think that making more than one assertion per-method is fine?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it (I base my thoughts on my personal experience and what I've ever read). Actually I would write it in exactly the same way.

Comment: as much as possible, I tend to go with one test method per method tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test method is testing this:

```
   $retobj = $this->hobj->newFoo();
```

in one test, and performing multiple assertions on this one object. That doesn't seem unreasonable.

I would be more concerned if you were testing multiple method invocations in the one test. Why ? An early assertion would abort the test and not perform a test on a further method. At *best* that means the second method wasn't tested, and at *worst* it hides evidence revealed by the 2nd test (that evidence could help identify the cause or scope of the first failure)

For this reason I do try to avoid too many assertions in the unit test method. It's not unreasonable to check for a null object, and then check (in the same test) for a populated field. I wouldn't chain those assertions together, though, and would rather have multiple tests testing different functionality of the same returned entity.

As ever, there's a degree of practicality to be applied here.

Comment: "that evidence could help identify the cause or scope of the first failure" --- and the opposite point of view: one small error could cause noise of 100 failed tests.

Comment: Not sure how you avoid the latter. Can you elucidate ?

Comment: I meant that multiple tests sometimes are more harm than useful, because if they test something tightly related - they likely would fail always together, thus would create a noise (which you wouldn't have if you had assertions in a single test method). So I agree with your answer that the tests length decision is a matter of practice and experience (that's why I +1'd it ;-)